# Pandas selecting previous row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For instance, I have a data frame below,

'''

```
id user_id actual_Y

1   10       renew

2   10       renew

3   10       cancel

4   15       renew

5   15       cancel

6   88       renew

7   88       renew
 
9   99       cancel
```

'''

I want to select user_id row with actual_Y ='cancel'  and its previous 2 rows
like this

'''

```
id user_id actual_Y

1   10       renew

2   10       renew

3   10       cancel

4   15       renew

5   15       cancel

9   99       cancel
```

'''

How can I achieve this and selecting previous rows general
like select only N previous rows
like select 1 previous rows result would be:
'''

id user_id actual_Y

2   10       renew

3   10       cancel

4   15       renew

5   15       cancel

9   99       cancel

'''

Answer (score 1):

Idea is create groups by values before `cancel` from back in cumulative sum and create mask for filter out groups without `cancel` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
N = 2

s = df['actual_Y'].eq('cancel').iloc[::-1].groupby(df['user_id']).cumsum().iloc[::-1]
mask = s.gt(0)
df1 = df[df.groupby(['user_id',s]).cumcount(ascending=False).le(N) & mask]
print (df1)
   id  user_id actual_Y
0   1       10    renew
1   2       10    renew
2   3       10   cancel
3   4       15    renew
4   5       15   cancel
7   9       99   cancel
```

---

```
N = 1

s = df['actual_Y'].eq('cancel').iloc[::-1].groupby(df['user_id']).cumsum().iloc[::-1]
mask = s.gt(0)
df2 = df[df.groupby(['user_id',s]).cumcount(ascending=False).le(N) & mask]
print (df2)
   id  user_id actual_Y
1   2       10    renew
2   3       10   cancel
3   4       15    renew
4   5       15   cancel
7   9       99   cancel
```

Comment: explain what is happening with iloc using ::-1

Comment: @Golden Lion not sure i think its working like shift(-1)

Comment: @GoldenLion - groups is necessary create from back/ bottom, so `::-1` is for swap ordering - If series is [1,2,3,5] then after swap get `[5,3,2,1]`